# Chat client which supports Voice Chat for Google and Yahoo

Tags: chat

Which chat client support voice chat for both Yahoo and Google.

Comment: Which OS should this be for?

Comment: Windows 7 OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't see the Voice Chat part at first. Here's an alternative:

[Instan-T](http://inidownload.com/it/Download/Completo/50/ItSetup.exe)

[image]

Instan-t Messenger is an easy-to-use, fully-featured and a very secured instant messaging client suitable for enterprises where you need to have access to multiple IM. It comes in two versions, a desktop client and a web-based version. Both of them allows you to chat with MSN, AOL, ICQ, Yahoo! and GTalk contacts and are developed to fully improve internal communications. It also features multiperson video chat room with your friends on other IM networks.

**Features**

- New multiperson video chat
- Interoperability with Google Talk
- Multiple ways to see your contact list
- Support for tabs in message window
- Contact list search
- Rename contacts on all networks
- Display picture
- Custom status text
- Webcam as display picture
- Improved toaster (online notification)
- New skins (Classic and Dusk

It contains no advertising, spyware and is absolutely free to use!

---

[Here are some choices suggested by Daniel Curran:](http://danielcurran.com/freeware/digsby-free-im/)

[image][Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.com/) (formerly called GAIM) is a chat program which lets you log in to accounts on multiple chat networks simultaneously. This means that you can be chatting with friends on MSN, talking to a friend on Google Talk, and sitting in a Yahoo chat room all at the same time.

---

[image] [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/?utm_campaign=new_n&utm_content=new&utm_medium=new&utm_source=new) is a multiprotocol IM client that lets you chat with all your friends on AIM, MSN, Yahoo, ICQ, Google Talk, and Jabber with one simple to manage buddy list. One combined buddy list for all your AIM, MSN, Yahoo, ICQ, Google Talk, Jabber, and Facebook Chat Accounts.

Digsby is an email notification tool that alerts you of new email and lets you perform actions such as ‘Delete’ or ‘Report Spam’ with just one click. Manage your Hotmail, Gmail, Yahoo Mail, AOL/AIM Mail, IMAP, and POP accounts right from digsby.

And Digsby is a social networking tool that alerts you of events like new messages and gives you a live Newsfeed of what your friends are up to. Manage your Hotmail, Gmail, Yahoo Mail, AOL/AIM Mail, IMAP, and POP accounts right from digsby. Stay up to date with everything happening on your Facebook, Twitter, MySpace and LinkedIn accounts.

---

[image] Hey Mac users! A mac version is in the works, until then I don’t want you to think I forgot you: Check  Out [Adium](http://www.adiumx.com/) for Mac. Adium is a free instant messaging application for Mac OS X that can connect to AIM, MSN, Jabber, Yahoo, and more.

Comment: I need to do voice chat. Pidgin is not permitting.

Comment: How about linking to a product page instead of a direct download!